# What's the meaning of "....don't you black or white me"

Tags: word-meaning, verbs, lyrics

> Beat me, hate me
>   You can never break me
>   Will me, thrill me
>   You can never kill me
>   Jew me, sue me
>   Everybody do me
>   Kick me, kike me
>   **Don't you black or white me**

It's from MJ's track, my favorite one. I understand the meaning that he wants says **'NO'** to racism but then are words *black* and *white* used as **verbs** here?

Also,

> Everybody **do** me?

Comment: You can verb every noun in English. (although verbing weirds the language).

Comment: Curb me, perturb me; in the end you'll verb me.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of song lyrics - which aren't necessarily representative of normal English, and which don't necessarily have an unambiguous meaning (they certainly don't in this case).

Comment: @FumbleFingers Surprisingly, the answers I'm getting make utter sense and are meaningful.

Comment: @Maulik V: I never suggested it wasn't possible to provide meaningful answers. But does "the" verb (or is it *two?*) reference racism, pigeon-holing in general, polarised/extremist thinking, some combination of all those and/or other elements? It's hopelessly subjective, and (maybe not in this particular case, I don't know) it's not uncommon to discover that even the *author* of song lyrics won't/can't specify *exactly* what they mean. Particularly when wordplay & rhyme are significant factors in the (non-standard) text.

Comment: @FumbleFingers This particular song had drawn everybody's attention as it has *meaningful lyrics* I guess. Also, as suggested in answers here, the line *black or white* is in flow conveying the message of very carefully written lyrics. You only said *....maybe not in this particular case* which means this question is quite askable. Anyway, I got the answer and chose as well. Thanks for your view though.

Comment: @Maulik: Well, I only get one vote the same as everyone else when it comes to what is or isn't On Topic here. I still think the first two comments (re the fact that English allows almost *anything* to be used as a verb) cover the only aspect of the question that really seems relevant to *learners*. Everything else seems to me to be a matter of interpretation/LitCrit. Which I don't deny is *interesting* - it's just not so relevant to ELL as most of your questions here (which are usually both interesting *and* likely to help other learners).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way I would interpret *black-and-white* (when used as a verb) would be:

> Don't put everything into [two] absolutes when you're talking with me.

Two common idioms are:

> It's black-and-white.
>   It's not black-and-white.

When something is either morally right or morally wrong, it's often said to be *black-and-white*, meaning that there are no shades of gray. For example, one might argue that *stealing* is wrong; it's simply not right to take what doesn't belong to you.

Someone else may counter, though, by pointing to the legend of Robin Hood. Though a thief, he was lionized, because he didn't steal for his own gain. Rather, he stole from the rich, and gave to the poor, who were being oppressed by the rich.

Some folks tend to see a lot of things in black-and-white, meaning they leave little wiggle room for "it depends on the circumstances." Others have more of a "shades of grey" worldview, meaning they understand there are exceptions to every rule, and certain situations call for going outside the lines.

NOAD reads:

> **black and white** *adj*. (of a situation or debate) involving clearly defined opposing principles or issues

---

In a cry against racism, "Don't you black-and-white me" has a nice dual meaning. On one hand, it says, "Don't judge me simply by the color of my skin." But it also can mean, "Don't be looking at the world like there is never any room for compromise." Those two thoughts feed off each other pretty well.

That said, song lyrics and poetry aren't always easy to decipher; people have been inserting meaning that wasn't every intended into song lyrics for a long time. I believe one of the Beatles once quipped that whenever someone offered some interpretation of one of their songs, they might go along with it if they liked what the person said – even if those ideas were never in their minds when they wrote the lyrics. So there's really no way to know for sure, unless the author happens to be a member of ELL, and wants to chime in.

That said, the dictionary meaning of *black and white* **can** be ascertained, so I believe this answer may still be of some use for the English learner, even if I've read too much into the songwriter's work.

Comment: There comes the question: black AND white and black OR white! Do they mean the same?

Comment: @Maulik - They could mean the same (if one is a variant of the other), but they wouldn't necessarily mean the same in all contexts. (Imagine buying a new car, and the dealer asks, "What color do you want? Black or white?")

Comment: J.R. I'm concerned about the lyrics there. Does black-and-white **there** mean the same (black or white)?

Comment: @Maulik - That's the problem with lyrics – not everything's black or white. :^) See what I did there? I used "or" instead of "and", but I'm guessing you still understood what I meant. But I think "and" is the better way to say it; go to [OneLook.com](http://www.onelook.com/?w=black+and+white&ls=a) to look up _black and white_, then change the search to _black or white_ and see what happens.

Comment: With ***or*** in the lyrics, I think it's open to the reading "don't black [me] or white me" as well as the reading "don't black-or-white me".

Answer (score 4):

Part of the meaning of "don't you black or white me" here is likely something like: "do not make me and my personality, style, behavior or my art the object of categorization by race." In other words "Be more concerned with who I am than with whether I'm black or white, or whether I'm 'trying to be white' or 'trying to be black', or whether any aspect of my personality has to do with conforming to racially motivated expectations."  It also likely has the double meaning of "do not make me the object of rigid 'black and white' categorization in general".

The first interpretation is strongly supported by the appearance of Kike in the previous line, and Jew before that. "Kike me" is a play on "kick" in the same line, and is probably a metaphor for name-calling.  "Kike me, but don't black or white me" may be something like "go ahead, call me something; it doesn't bother me as long as you're only mouthing off (to be shocking or whatever), and are not adopting the underlying categorization as your actual mode of reasoning (even when you're silent)."

Answer (score 3):

I agree with you. I'm familiar with *black and white*, and I think it can be used as a verb. (Isn't it amazing that I can say *I "google" every day* in English?) I think the *black or white* in the lyric, *Don't you black or white me*, can be interpreted as either *Don't you (black or white) me* or *(Don't you black me) or (Don't you white me)*.

As for *Everybody do me*, it sounds pretty much like the use of *do* in the title of the movie ***Beavis and Butt-Head Do America*** to me, thought it should be *does*. But then again, this is a lyric. (I think I get his sub-text about *everybody* is not just one person, and *do* is not just about one single doing.) In this context, I interpret this line as: Everybody [did/does/can do/and might continue to do] all the mentioned nasty things mentioned in the previous lines.

Comment: Oh, you made me miss him and his great works. RIP, MJ.

Comment: You mention that it's the same as the movie title, but don't share your interpretation of the title. I interpret the title as a nod to [_Debbie Does Dallas_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debbie_Does_Dallas), an interpretation bolstered by the central plot point in [_Beavis and Butt-head Do America_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beavis_and_Butt-head_Do_America) being a confusion over the meaning of "do" with regards to a character named Dallas. I think "do me" in the MJ lyric is ambiguous between sex and the sense of "do you", i.e. be yourself and disregard detractors.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung I agree. My own interpretation of this *do me* was that it was about the same as *wrong me*, and in more than one way. And I was too shy to mention them explicitly.

Comment: I think your edit is a good one.